# A decomposition theorem for maximum weight matchings

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, matching

The following paper presents a way to solve the maximum weight matching of a bipartite graph by reducing it to computing maximum weight matchings of two lighter bipartite graphs:

M.-Y. Kao, T. W. Lam, W.-K. Sung, and H.-F. Ting. [A decomposition theorem
for maximum weight bipartite matchings with applications to evolutionary
trees](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48481-7_38). In Proc. of the 7th Annual European Symposium on Algorithms (ESA’99),
pages 438–449, 1999.

Is there a generalization of the result which also holds for non-bipartite weighted graphs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Are you actually looking for a polynomial time algorithm solving maximum weight matching for general graphs, or a specific way to solve it using a kind of decomposition?

In the former case, the following paper gives an $\mathcal{O}\big(n(m + \log n)\big)$ exact algorithm:
[H.N.Gabow. Data Structures for Weighted Matching and Nearest Common Ancestors witk Linking. SODA'90 (1990)](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320176.320229)
And for a $(2/3 - \epsilon)$-approximation algorithm running in $\mathcal{O}(m \log 1/\epsilon)$:
[S.Pettie, P.Sanders. A Simpler Linear $2/3 - \epsilon$ Approximation Algorithm for Maximum Weight Matching. Information Processing Letters, vol.91 (2004)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2004.05.007)

Comment: I am interested in a similar decomposition.